# Why do indexed mapped types appear to behave the same for 0 depth tuples and for all depth objects, but not for > 0 depth tuples?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a generic type that when parametrized with some object type, will form a new type allowing only any path that is present in the object type. I have adapted my solution from here: [How to match nested Keys in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56605358/how-to-match-nested-keys-in-typescript)

While this solution works for objects, it does not behave properly for tuples, when the tuple is not top-level. Why is this?

I believe the answer may lie in my lack of understanding of mapped types and typescript types, specifically with regard to the behavior of indexing and keyof. The only place I have been able to find documentation of the combination of these two things together is [here in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (cmd+f "[keyof").

I have seen a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644053/how-to-retrieve-a-type-from-a-nested-property-using-a-path-tuple) that would mostly accomplish my goal, but at this point I'm in a bit of a bloodlust and just want to understand why my current solution is failing. That other answer is a whole other can of worms: I have found that if you change [...keys to keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ts=4.2.0-dev.20201109#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCcIEMAmB7AdgDYhQAKaukaocIA2gLoDcAsAFCiRQAiEEYASXzYIADwA8AFQA0sAMpQxwCMKS0EsgGKYAloRRQArsIgAzHfgjYAfCnZQH8xaOWqodC6Yhoom2QDpAz28oACUGKHtHaIB+X2dXbCQAa3hcUyhJKOicqDjQhJUk2HgkbNyKuN5+IREJSTpNBllQrV1Ca3KKnIAuX3bItm7ovu09Lsc+yVY2dlNjAGNgHQIoERqTetkYBSUitVLtwrdySm8aeGsAClwAIwArKdlUxD6dqAAyWEYASj7qwSbKTbOTWGbzfBLFb4NZ8QF1G4PPqYfAgZ6lN6lH5QADe5QwwEMaBhLwQ-gw2EMCwgVxuz2xyFsuBi-joyWaUDu9x+MwAvux2AsCAhgJyHgY8UNHJg+jioLdZVAFn0AIxQXmybCKiB9ABEuvV6uk5VMioA5oqABaKnR9YBoQzQXmGjVQR64qDJPp0OWEPWW+AG3kRflsUOC4WihYGdbwsSI+6yOi6zC62S625pqC6ha6hg8qAAekLUHwhgAtrcQhH8CLFDG4bV41ykyms7rsO2IHmC8WoCK0BYzTW6zoGxsES33LrTO2ze3Le2dD2mEWS7dcLhCFh8CPRfpULGm6IE637u3klmAAzpwgrtf9+1DvecyhIQ+Nzan6ep9OZ9O5umnb5qufbGCI5iWNgL6WuW5bjnGJ5Tsmv7Zv+2aAdmwC4JoOiiFY959lcphoJgUIENwOhmjowAIDEfRlpW3gMrYA7PmwQA), <strike>it stops working, which confuses me even further.</strike> - These [seems](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ts=4.2.0-dev.20201109#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oCcIEMAmB7AdgDYhQAKaukaocIA2gLoDcAsAFCiRQAiEEYASXzYIADwA8AFQA0sAMpQxwCMKS0EsgGKYAloRRQArsIgAzHfgjYAfCnZQH8xaOWqodC6Yhoom2QDpAz28oACUGKHtHaIB+X2dXbCQAa3hcUyhJKOicqDjQhJUk2HgkbNyKuN5+IREJSTpNBllQrV1Ca3KKnIAuX3bItm7ovu09Lsc+yVY2dlNjAGNgHQIoERqTetkYBSUitVLtwrdySm8aeGsAClwAIwArKdlUxD6dqAAyWEYASj7qwSbKTbOTWGbzfBLFb4NZ8QF1G4PPqYfAgZ6lN6lH5QADe5QwwEMaBhLwQ-gw2EMCwgVxuz2xyFsuBi-joyWaUDu9x+MwAvux2JxoAB5B7IHGYPo425ShZ9BDANAWADmvP5HHA0FImGAAAtkHQAESYQ3SQ23U2GhaGhgCtgLAgKqALAzreFicSi+7SbV66QKpX4ZXXCU9aVhuWG3UQQiEXCGtW82RGk2yc2mqBWm08qAAelzUHwhgAtrcQnagA) to be due to type inference.

```typescript
// Note: using 4.1.3

// Expect this to take an object and produce as a type the paths that are accessible in the object

type Path<V> = {
  [K in keyof V]:
    Path<V[K]> extends any[]
      ? [K, ...Path<V[K]>]
      : never
    | [K]
    | []
}[keyof V]

// Example objects

type InputArrayType = [
  string,
  string,
  string
]

type InputNestedDictType = {
  a: {
    aa: string
  },
  b: {
    ba: string
  }
}

type InputNestedArrayType = [
  [
    string,
    string
  ],
  [
    string,
    string
  ], {
    a: string
  }
]

// Expectations that are working properly:

const path0: Path<InputArrayType> = ["0"]; // okay
const path1: Path<InputArrayType> = ["3"]; // expected type error
const path2: Path<InputNestedDictType> = ["a"] // okay
const path3: Path<InputNestedDictType> = ["a","aa"] // okay
const path4: Path<InputNestedDictType> = ["a","ba"] // expected type error
const path5: Path<InputNestedDictType> = ["z"] // expected type error
const path6: Path<InputNestedArrayType> = ["0"] // okay
const path7: Path<InputNestedArrayType> = ["2","a"] // okay

// Expectations that are not working properly:

const path8: Path<InputNestedArrayType> = ["0","0"] // Unexpected type error
```